# Build the static Opencv library with multi-threaded debug DLL (/MDd) C runtime library

Tags: c++, opencv

I am now trying to build opencv with cmake, and if I use the following command:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

I can build a static OPENCV libary. However, the built library links C run time library statically. In VC2010, it uses Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) option. What I expects is to link C run time library dynamically, and that is using /MDd option in VC2010, then what can I do to make it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you need partial static and partial dynamic?

Comment: @guneykayim Thanks for your comments. I am now using boost unit-test framework, and within this framework using dynamic C run time library is the only choice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `-DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=OFF` to CMake command line:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=OFF ..
```